# Forcing text to the right-hand-sideof the page

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'm wondering how (if possible) to force text to the right hand side in LaTeX.

So, you know when you have a set of simultaneous equations and the equation reads from the left, but then over on the right there is a number indicating which equation it is for later use...?

Something like:

```
2x + 6y + z = x ... [and then like way over here ----> ]...     -(1

3x + 4y + z = y ... [and then like way over here ----> ]...     -(2

3x + 5y + z = z ... [and then like way over here ----> ]...     -(3

x + y + z = 1 ..... [and then like way over here ----> ]...     -(4
```

How would I get the (1, (2  etc.. to the RHS?

Sorry if this is unclear, I have no idea how else to explain it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two ways presented in order to typeset your equations. Obviously, there are a lot more ways to do that but this answer just wants to show two simple ways, leaving it up to you if you want something more sophisticated.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
2x + 6y + z = x
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
3x + 4y + z = y
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
3x + 5y + z = z
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
x + y + z = 1
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
2x + 6y + z &= x\\
3x + 4y + z &= y\\
3x + 5y + z &= z\\
x + y + z &= 1
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The second bunch of equations is used to align them all to the `=` sign using the `&`. By default the equations will be centered but it is possible to get them left aligned by adding the `fleqn` option to the `amsmath` package.

[image: Output]